# Keycloak - Sharing Session Across Protocols (SAML & OIDC)

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid-connect, openid, saml-2.0

Using Keycloak, I understand that you can configure apps that use OIDC and SAML within the same realm and have done so.

But, can someone confirm whether you can share sessions across protocols?

I have tested with 4 applications, 2 using SAML and 2 using OIDC, all within the same realm.
From my testing the 2 OIDC apps are sharing a session and the 2 SAML apps are sharing a different session. Thus to login to the 4 apps, the user needs to login twice (once for SAML and once for OIDC).

**Can someone confirm whether both protocols can share sessions?**

*I am using Keycloak as IdP in the above tests.*

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem  ? ;)

Comment: got any solution for this problem ? :D

Comment: any solution for this?